# T-SQL Creating nested XML based on a GROUP BY Column

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, group-by, nested

I have table data that looks like this:

```
CustomerID ProductCode ProductPrice
1           P001        1.20
1           P002        3.6
1           P003        5.3
2           P001         30
2           P003        20
```

I'd like to use T-SQL XML to produce output like this:

```
<Sales>
  <Customer id="1">
     <Sale>
        <ProductCode>P001</ProductCode>
        <Price>1.20</Price>
     </Sale>
     <Sale>
        <ProductCode>P002</ProductCode>
        <Price>3.6</Price>
     </Sale>
     <Sale>
        <ProductCode>P003</ProductCode>
        <Price>5.3</Price>
     </Sale>
  </Customer>
  <Customer id="2">
    <Sale>
         <ProductCode>P001</ProductCode>
         <Price>30</Price>
    </Sale>
    <Sale>
       <ProductCode>P003</ProductCode>
       <Price>20</Price>
    </Sale>
  </Customer>
</Sales>
```

I have tried using:

```
SELECT CustomerID as "@id"
      ProductCode as "Sale/ProductCode",
      ProducPrice as "Sale/ProductPrice"
FROM myTable as Sale
Order by CustID
FOR XML PATH('Customer'), ROOT('Sales'), ELEMENTS
```

And the output I am getting is not exactly what I want. I am getting:

```
<Sales>
  <Sale>
   <Customer id="1">
     <ProductCode>P001</ProductCode>
     <ProductPrice>1.2</ProductPrice>
   </Customer>
  </Sale>
  <Sale>
   <Customer id="1">
     <ProductCode>P002</ProductCode>
     <ProductPrice>3.6</ProductPrice>
   </Customer>
 </Sale>
 <Sale>
  <Customer id="1">
     <ProductCode>P003</ProductCode>
     <ProductPrice>5.3</ProductPrice>
  </Customer>
 </Sale>
 <Sale>
  <Customer id="2">
     <ProductCode>P001</ProductCode>
     <ProductPrice>30</ProductPrice>
  </Customer> 
 </Sale>
 <Sale>
   <Customer id="2">
     <ProductCode>P003</ProductCode>
     <ProductPrice>20</ProductPrice>
  </Customer>
 </Sale>
</Sales>
```

I do not want the Customer tag to keep repeating as above. I would like just one Customer tag with nested sales inside it. So its a bit like a "GROUP BY Customer ID". How can I achive this. Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT  CustomerID as "@id"
     , (SELECT ProductCode
              ,ProductPrice
        FROM TableName t
        WHERE Sale.CustomerID = t.CustomerID
        FOR XML PATH('Sale'), TYPE
       )
FROM (
Select DISTINCT CustomerID 
FROM TableName) as Sale
Order by CustomerID
FOR XML PATH('Customer'), ROOT('Sales'), ELEMENTS
```

**Result**

```
<Sales>
  <Customer id="1">
    <Sale>
      <ProductCode>P001</ProductCode>
      <ProductPrice>1.20</ProductPrice>
    </Sale>
    <Sale>
      <ProductCode>P002</ProductCode>
      <ProductPrice>3.60</ProductPrice>
    </Sale>
    <Sale>
      <ProductCode>P003</ProductCode>
      <ProductPrice>5.30</ProductPrice>
    </Sale>
  </Customer>
  <Customer id="2">
    <Sale>
      <ProductCode>P001</ProductCode>
      <ProductPrice>30.00</ProductPrice>
    </Sale>
    <Sale>
      <ProductCode>P003</ProductCode>
      <ProductPrice>20.00</ProductPrice>
    </Sale>
  </Customer>
</Sales>
```

Comment: @Ceasar, if the above answer has answered your question, do consider marking the answer as accepted

Comment: Sorry @M.Ali - wasn't conversant with the ettiquette. Thanks!